# count how many group in a column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

using `count()` and `group by` I can generate a `count` belong with that group.

example:

**DB**

```
 student_number            sem              SY
    2015-0002            2nd sem          2014-2015
    2015-0002            2nd sem          2014-2015
    2015-0002            2nd sem          2014-2015
    2015-0002            1st sem          2015-2016
    2015-0002            1st sem          2015-2016
    2015-0002            1st sem          2015-2016
    2015-0002            2nd sem          2015-2016
    2015-0002            2nd sem          2015-2016
    2015-0002            2nd sem          2015-2016
    2015-0002            2nd sem          2015-2016
```

query

```
  $sql  = "SELECT *, count(SY) as student_count ";
  $sql .= "FROM studeaccount ";
  $sql .= "WHERE StudentNumber = '2015-0002' ";
  $sql .= "GROUP BY SY, Sem ";
  $sql .= "ORDER BY StudentNumber ASC";
```

query above output like this:

```
2nd sem : 2014-2015 = 3
1st sem : 2015-2016 = 3
2nd sem : 2015-2016 = 4
```

result above show number of group and that what i want to get, the total number of group. example below i want to output.

```
Group count = 3 // this is what i want to achieve.
```

hope this help.

Comment: that you can achieve using PHP!!

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected output ?

Comment: I think you can achieve this using a sub-select, first group the column `SY` and afterwords count them in the outter `SELECT`

Comment: do you have some example please.

Comment: You should provide more information about your DB structure, or explain better what you have and what are you looking for.

Comment: update my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
    SELECT *, count(SY) as student_count
    FROM studeaccount
    WHERE StudentNumber = '2015-0002'
    GROUP BY SY, Sem
    ORDER BY StudentNumber ASC
 ) t1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$sql = "select count(distinct sem) from student_account";
```